VSCode debugger attachment to docker container
I'm having docker container which runs web and api application with two different ports.
Is it possible to attach my vscode debugger to the docker container?
I'm using node apps for both
Mostly the command to run both applicaiton is npm run dev
Please share any helpful methods to achieve this.
